# Как вычислить значение кусочно-заданной функции?

Tags: java

По учёбе в институте задали несколько заданий, это одно из них. Остальные легко сделал, а это сложное, потому что это система уравнений.

Задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам смог написать вот только такой код:

```
public class task {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double a = 4.9;
        final double b = 1.3;

         //первая строчка:
        double x = 4.27;
        double result1 = Math.pow(Math.E, (b*x-1));
        System.out.println(result1); //выдаёт: 94.72708805521908

        //вторая строчка:
        x = 8.5;
        double result2 = (1/(a*Math.pow(x, 3)+1));
        System.out.println(result2); //выдаёт: 3.322024607897283E-4

        //третья строчка
        x = -1.48;
        double ax_in2pow = Math.pow((a*x), 2); //(a*x)^2
        double result3 = Math.log( Math.sqrt(1+ax_in2pow) );
        System.out.println(result3); //выдаёт: 1.990695274025217
    }
}
```

Вроде все три ответа должны же быть одинаковые в системе...

Comment: Вы не справились с заданием, так как у вас нет _одной_ функции, значения которой вычисляются в зависимости от значения аргумента `x`: `static double f(double x) { if (x <= 2) return (3).. else if (x < 7) return .(1)..; return (2);}` (в скобках соответствующие формулы).  Затем вызываете функцию с заданными аргументами и печатаете ее значение

Comment: *это сложное, потому что это система уравнений.* Мне жаль Вас огорчать, но это НЕ система уравнений.

Comment: Здесь нет системы уравнений.

Comment: @user522913, прочитайте, что такое [кусочно-заданная функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кусочно-заданная_функция), и переформулируйте вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1455577/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нет ничего сложного. Вы должны применить разные уравнения для вычисления `у` в зависимости от значения `х`, а не решить систему уравнений в классическом понимании. Посему выглядит это примерно так:

```
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;

public class Test {

    private static final double a = 4.9;
    private static final double b = 1.3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleStream.of(4.27, 8.5, -1.48).forEach(x -> System.out.println("f(" + x + ") = " + f(x)));
    }

    public static double f(double x) {
        if (x >= 7) return 1 / (a * Math.pow(x, 3) + 1);
        if (x <= 2) return Math.log(Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow((a * x), 2)));
        return Math.pow(Math.E, (b * x - 1));
    }

}
```