# Рассчитать значения функции f(x) в целочисленном интервале Python (Вычислить значение y)

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дана функция, вычисляющая значение переменной y в зависимости от переменной a и x. Дан интервал целых чисел, которые может принимать переменная a и x.

1)Необходимо написать программу на языке Python, которая вычислит значение y
2)Трижды нужно протестировать программу используя исходные данные с картинки

```
import math
a = float(input())
x = float(math.sin(0.5 * a))
if (a <= 0 and x <= 0):
    y = 3 * math.sqrt((a + 1) ** 2) / math.sqrt(math.abc(a) + x)
    print(y)
elif (0 <= a and a <= 1) and (0 <= x and x <= 1):
    y = (math.tan(x + (a / math.pi))) ** 2
    print(y)
elif (a >= 1 and x >= 1):
    y = math.log10((a + (math.e)** (a * x)) ** 2)
    print(y)
```

Comment: И что именно у вас не получилось запрограммировать для решения данной задачи?

Comment: 2.1 - это совсем не целое число даже в питоне

Comment: @Nowhere Man
Я новичек в питоне не как не могу понять как решить ее ,а завтро нужно представить решение

Comment: похожий вопрос [на джаве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1455577/), там даже сердобольный ответ имеется

Comment: @РанисДаишев, найдите и почитайте какой нибудь туториал: [числа и функции](https://codechick.io/tutorials/python/numbers-and-math-functions), [условный оператор `if-elif-else`](https://codechick.io/tutorials/python/if-elif-else)

Comment: Тут мало кого волнует, что ты новичок и что завтра надо представить решение. Если сам ничего не делаешь, то и помогать нечему.

Comment: @Nowhere Man
В чем ошибка?

Comment: @РанисДаишев, какая ошибка?

Comment: @Nowhere Man Запускаю код нечего не происходит

Comment: @Nowhere Man На сколько близок к решению задачи

Comment: Ошибка в том, что нужно проверять произведение `a*x` на попадание в диапазон, а не использовать логическое `and` :), и для определения последнего диапазона следует использовать `else`, а не `elif`

Comment: В целом, очень близко к решению

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки, которые бросаются в глаза:

- корень третьей степени - это не тоже самое, что 3 умножить на квадратный корень
- `ax` сравнить с чем-то - проверять нужно сравнивая `a * x` с указанным, а не отдельно `a` и отдельно `x`, результат будет неправильный
- `<=` и `<` - это не одно и то же, будьте внимательнее
- логарифм натуральный и логарифм десятичный - это разное, не путайте

То, что код написан не оптимально при этом - это в общем ерунда, но настолько путать существенные вещи именно с математической точки зрения - это очень небрежно с вашей стороны, будьте внимательнее.